# ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1, 2) and (2,)

Tags: python, scipy

I want to find maxima and minima from a list, but after running my program, terminal shows error like "ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1, 2) and (2,),". How to fix this problem?

Code:

```
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

data = np.array([-1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 1 ])
plt.plot(data)


maximums = argrelextrema(data, np.greater) 

plt.plot(maximums, data[maximums], "x")

minimums = np.array(argrelextrema(data, np.less))

plt.plot(minimums, data[minimums], ".")

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.argrelextrema.html), `maxima` and `minima` are not 1 dimensional arrays but tuples of ndarrays

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array([-1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 1 ])

maxima = argrelextrema(data, np.greater) 
minima = argrelextrema(data, np.less)
```

let's check

```
print(maxima)
```

gives

```
(array([ 3, 11]),)
```

and

```
print(minima)
```

gives

```
(array([7]),)
```

Since you need the first element only of the tuple, you can do

```
plt.plot(data)
plt.plot(maxima[0], data[maxima[0]], "x", ms=10)
plt.plot(minima[0], data[minima[0]], ".", ms=10)
plt.show()
```

[image]